# Read vs Copy a message from JMS queue..using logstash into ES

Tags: jms, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

At times, we find a need to Read a "copy" of the msg from the JMS queue and store it in a data-store ( eg. ElasticSearch). 
In an enterprise landscape, when System-A   sends a XML msg  to System-B  via JMS queue, if another System-C can probe and READ A COPY of the msg (not remove it from the JMS Queue after reading but just read a copy of the msg) 
and store it for auditing/searching/analysis eg. in ElasticSearch Datastore. Then we can do auditing/search-analysis of the data using Kibana on top of Elasticsearch.

So question is - we can use Logstash or a logstash plugin to read a JMS msg but cannot just read a copy of the msg.  Is there any way to do this ?

logstash-plugin --> read frm JMS queue --> send it to ES --> Use Kibana to analyze the data from ES.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a JMS Topic instead of a Queue you could write the message to the Topic and have System B and System C both subscribe and consume the message.

See:

[JMS Topic vs Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576415/jms-topic-vs-queues)

[How to "copy" a JMS message to 2 destinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581623/how-to-copy-a-jms-message-to-2-destinations)

UPDATE: From speaking with original poster they can't move the architecture to Topics so I suggested composite/virtual destinations.

http://activemq.apache.org/composite-destinations.html

http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html